# Convert SVG to PNG/JPEG with custom width and height

Tags: javascript, html, image, svg, html5-canvas

I have a SVG code with width and height. I want to download this SVG in PNG and JPEG Format with custom width and Height.
I have tried HTML canvas approach to achieve this but when canvas draws image it crops out the SVG.

Here is the Code

SVG Code

```
<svg id="svgcontent" width="640" height="480" x="640" y="480" overflow="visible" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:se="http://svg-edit.googlecode.com" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 640 480"><!-- Created with SVG-edit - https://github.com/SVG-Edit/svgedit--><g class="layer" style="pointer-events:all"><title style="pointer-events:inherit">Layer 1</title><ellipse fill="#FF0000" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="5" cx="280.5" cy="235.5" rx="217" ry="198" id="svg_1"></ellipse></g></svg>
```

JavaScript Function for conversion of SVG to png/jpeg

```
    function save() {
// Converting SVG to String 
    var stringobJ = new XMLSerializer();
      var svg = document.getElementById('svgcontent');
      var svgString = stringobJ .serializeToString(svg );
// IE9 doesn't allow standalone Data URLs
      svg = '<?xml version="1.0"?>\n' + svgString ; 

// Creating an Image Element
      var image = new Image();
      image.src = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + btoa(svg);
      image.width = 300; // This doesn't have any effect
      image.height = 150; // This doesn't have any effect

// Creating Canvas Element 
      var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      image.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.download = "image.png"; //Saving in PNG
        a.href = canvas.toDataURL('image/png'); //Saving in PNG
        a.style = 'display: none;';
        a.click();
      }
    }
```

It gives me Imgae in PNG format but its not complete image of SVG its just the part of image according to width of canvas bcz canvas draws image from top right corner of image and it goes on drawing image till width and height of canvas.

By default canvas width is 300 and height is 150

So if canvas width and height is not give its just outputs and image of 300x150.

I have tried `canvas.width = anyvalue;
             canvas.height= anyvalue;`
but it doesn't effect the output

## **what i want is**

that no matter what is the dimensions of SVG 
when user gives width and height the SVG should completely fit in canvas

This is the Actual SVG and this actually needed on download with all white background and image

[image: X]

this is this is the output but i want full image with these dimensions

[image: X]

Giving width and height to canvas as actual SVG have is not a solution to my problem..... width and height of canvas is dynamic

[jsfiddle link to the problem](https://jsfiddle.net/t0jhnb1d/3/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a few changes:
your svg `viewBox="0 0 640 480"`. This defines the size of the SVG canvas. When you draw the image (unless you want to crop it) you want to keep the height proportional, i.e. if you want the width to be 300 the height should be 225.

Then when you create a new canvas element you need to declare the width and the height of the canvas element `canvas.width = image.width, canvas.height = image.height,`before drawing the image.

```js
function save() {
// Converting SVG to String 
    var stringobJ = new XMLSerializer();
      var svg = document.getElementById('svgcontent');
      var svgString = stringobJ .serializeToString(svg );
// IE9 doesn't allow standalone Data URLs
      svg = '<?xml version="1.0"?>\n' + svgString ; 

// Creating an Image Element
      var image = new Image();
      image.src = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + btoa(svg);
      image.width = 300; 
      image.height = 480*image.width / 640; // keep the height proportional

// Creating Canvas Element 
      var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      
      image.onload = function() {
        canvas.width = image.width,canvas.height = image.height,
        
        context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.download = "image.png"; //Saving in PNG
        a.href = canvas.toDataURL('image/png'); //Saving in PNG
        a.style = 'display: none;';
        a.click();
      }
    }

//save()
```

```html
<svg id="svgcontent" viewBox="0 0 640 480" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:se="http://svg-edit.googlecode.com" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><!-- Created with SVG-edit - https://github.com/SVG-Edit/svgedit-->
<g class="layer" style="pointer-events:all">
<title style="pointer-events:inherit">Layer 1</title>
<ellipse fill="#FF0000" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="5" cx="280.5" cy="235.5" rx="217" ry="198" id="svg_1"></ellipse>
</g>
</svg>
```